# How to Use vue-tags-input in Nuxtjs 3 App

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

Does anyone have any idea how to use vue-tags-input with Nuxtjs v3? It looks like the documentation is entirely centered toward Nuxt v2. I tried adding it as a plugin as `~/plugins/vue-tags-input.client.ts`

```
import VueTagsInput from '@johmun/vue-tags-input';

export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
    nuxtApp.vueApp.use(VueTagsInput);
})
```

Not sure if I did that right, but it's not showing at all on the frontend now. Any ideas?

Comment: It's a component, not a plugin, should be nuxtApp.vueApp.component(VueTagsInput) if you want to register it globally. It's possible it won't work with vue 3 at all. That it doesn't mention vue 3 and is not updated means it's for vue 2

Comment: Have you tried this package? https://github.com/sipec/vue-tags-input Forked from the package that you use